# Subclassing UIViewController With NavigationBar Title

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to subclass a `UIViewController` with a label (`UILabel`) set to the title of the navigation bar.  Instead of setting a name to self.title, I want to use an attributed string to set the title.

```
class BasicViewController: UIViewController {
    var titleString = ""

    func setup() {
        //self.title = titleString
        let navBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
        navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        let atext = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleString)
        atext.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, atext.length))
        atext.addAttribute(NSStrokeColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, atext.length))
        atext.addAttribute(NSStrokeWidthAttributeName, value: NSNumber.init(float: -1.0), range: NSMakeRange(0, atext.length))
        let titleLabel:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(50, 3, 220, 44))
        titleLabel.attributedText = atext
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 24.0)
    }
}

class HomeViewController: BasicViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleString = "My App"
        setup()
    }
}
```

If I run this code, I get an empty title.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Is `titleLabel` ever added to any view? 

You can use the following didSet method btw, so you do not have to run `setup()` after setting the string.

```var titleString = "" { 
    didSet {
        let navBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
        (...)
    }
}```

Comment: titleLbel can be added to the navigation bar if I directly insert the lines of code inside of setup() with HomeViewController's viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're setting `self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel`